# ASP.Net web application is ignoring global.asax file and code behind changes

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, global-asax

I have an ASP.Net 4.0 web forms application that is ignoring any changes I make in the code in the code behind files and also in the global.asax.

I've tried using the built in web server in Visual Studio 2010, local IIS and on my web host.  I've tried cleaning and rebuilding the project; that didn't help.  I've even tried excluding the global.asax file from my application just so I could see it error out, but the app still runs!  It's like it has it cached somewhere that I can't update.

I'm hoping this is simple, but I'm perplexed none-the-less.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try with a new application and see if that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I went to the bin folder I saw an old dll, which made me remember that I had previously named the project something else.  I deleted the old dll files and then went to the obj folder and completely removed the entire Debug folder and it's contents.

When I tried to run the web application it displayed an error.  The error was "Could not load type old_namespace.global_asax".  I went through the application and replaced all the old_namespace references with the new_namespace.  When I run the application it works perfectly and honors changes that I make to the code.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

After any changes you make to cs files or Global.asax or web.config, you should always rebuild the project or solution to see the changes. Otherwise they won't take affect.

This happens because all your code compiles into a single assembly which can be found in bin folder. This file isn't overwritten until the next rebuild.

On the other hand, changes to the HTML pages and CSS and can be seen without rebuilding the project

Comment: I guess I omitted that in the question.  I have done a clean and rebuild on several (12+) occasions during my troubleshooting process.

Comment: On web server, you will need to replace the yourApp.dll and yourApp.pdb in bin folder....

Comment: Do one thing....In Visual studio, open the bin folder and delete the application assembly and pdb file. Then again do a rebuild of your project and see if changes are reflected

Answer (score 0):

Clear the Temporary ASP.NET Files cache and rebuild your solution. You can locate the folder under the following directory.

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319*

Rebuild your application and re-deploy it.

*Note: Change the version as per your selected framework.